# Laravel table is not recognized despite being present in the migrations

Tags: laravel

I am working on a project using laravel 6. Everything worked fine, but now I get following error:

```
("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lar-test.video_categories' doesn't exist")
```

The video_categories table exists:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('video_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name',128);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('video_categories');
    }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly: You 1. made the migration. 2. did `php artisan migrate`. 3. had no errors. 4. laravel cannot find the table? What does your db-tool find in your db?

Comment: The DB now is empty. If I call the command php artisan migrate I get the error above

Comment: Thats weird. Just to be sure, you have 0 tables in your db?

Comment: Yey, the DB is tempy. No tables.

Comment: Then the error should not be able to be caused by the `php artisan migrate` command itself. Did you maybe add any middleware to the project that tries to load something from the `video_categories` table? Or have any other reference that tries to load something from that table?

Comment: No middleware for video_categories